# PyQt5 Second Window flickers when resize event is passed to it from Main Window

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, parameter-passing, popupwindow

I am trying to figure out how to pass event data such as size of the main window to secondary windows. I was able to get this to work but my problem is the second window flickering every time the data is updated when resizing the main window and I'm struggling with  getting it to stop.

Here is my current code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# widget to which dimensions are passed
class Dimensions(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        font = QFont('Sans', 20)
        view_width = QLabel(self)

        view_width.setFont(font)
        view_width.setText(str(width))
        view_width.adjustSize()
        view_width.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        view_height = QLabel(self)

        view_height.setFont(font)
        view_height.setText(str(height))
        view_height.adjustSize()
        view_height.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        horizontal_layout.addWidget(view_width)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(view_height)
        self.setLayout(horizontal_layout)

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        # dimensions widget applied to second window
        dimensions_win = Dimensions(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(dimensions_win)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(0,0,640,480)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.width = event.size().width()
        self.height = event.size().height()
        # dimensions of main window passed to second window
        self.second_window = SecondWindow(self.width, self.height)
        self.second_window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_Window = MainWindow()
    Main_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There are lots of problems with your code, but the main one is that you're constantly recreating a `SecondWindow` instance. It's also unclear if you just want to display the new size in the secondary window or you also want to update its size (which is a bit weird requirement, I've to say).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Ultimately, the goal is to change the size of child widgets based on the size of main window but I also want to learn how to pass and update information in secondary windows. I did assume that the flicker was caused by SecondWindow recreation so how do I open the SecondWindow followed by leaving it open and updating its labels with new data, in this case size?

Comment: maybe create `SecondWindow` in `MainWindow.__init__` and use `self` in `self.dimensions_win` to have access to this variable as `self.second_window.dimensions_win`. And the same with `self.view_width` to have access `self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))`

Comment: @TommyG if your purpose is to "change the size of child widgets based on the size of main window", then you should properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @musicmante What about a situation where the child widget of a size for example 500x500 is within a MainWindow 1920x1080. As far as what I know about layouts when the MainWindow is scaled down to say 1280x720 the child widget will not scale down proportionally because the MainWindow will still be large enough to accommodate it so it will only shift in position. Also, what about font sizes?

Comment: @furas Can you clarify with a simple example? I'm still very new to the concepts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added more description in answer.

Comment: @TommyG the responsibility of layout managers is to ensure that they are always shown at optimal size by using as much space they need to properly display their contents. If the child widget has to be proportionally resized, then you should properly set the stretch of its size policy and also eventually add proper spacers or set valid stretch sizes to the (parent) layouts. Qt already takes care of font sizes (also considering screen DPI), so if you have issues with proportional sizes the problem is in your layout management and should **not** be done manually using arbitrary sizes.

Comment: @musicamante Thank for the explanation about the layout managers. I had experimented with them already but not as much with the stretch so I'll have a look at that more closely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create `SecondWindow()` in `resizeEvent` because when you resize main window then `resizeEvent` creates again and again `SecondWindow()` and Python removes old second window (assigned to `self.second_window`) - and there is short time when old window is already removed and new window still doesn't exist - and you see it as `flickering`.

You shoud create second window only once - in `__init__` - and later only replace text in `QLabel` in `Dimensions()`. But you use local variables (without `self.`) `dimensions_win`, `view_width`, `view_height` so it can't be accessed outside `Dimensions()` and `SecondWindow()`.

So you should use `self.` in

- `self.dimensions_win`
- `self.view_width`
- `self.view_height`

and then you can change text in `Dimensions()` without creating `SecondWindow()` again.

```
# dimensions of main window passed to second window

self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))
```

---

Full working code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# widget to which dimensions are passed
class Dimensions(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        font = QFont('Sans', 20)
        
        self.view_width = QLabel(self)

        self.view_width.setFont(font)
        self.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.view_width.adjustSize()
        self.view_width.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.view_height = QLabel(self)

        self.view_height.setFont(font)
        self.view_height.setText(str(height))
        self.view_height.adjustSize()
        self.view_height.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.view_width)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.view_height)
        self.setLayout(horizontal_layout)

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        # dimensions widget applied to second window
        self.dimensions_win = Dimensions(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dimensions_win)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)

        self.second_window = SecondWindow(640, 480)
        self.second_window.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = event.size().width()
        height = event.size().height()

        # dimensions of main window passed to second window
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_Window = MainWindow()
    Main_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also check if second window is not closed and reopen it.

```
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = event.size().width()
        height = event.size().height()

        # if closed then reopen
        if not self.second_window.isVisible():
            self.second_window.show()
            
        # dimensions of main window passed to second window
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Keep `MainWindow` size in `SecondWindow`

`SecondWindow` in `__init__` set at start

```
        self.main_window_width = width
        self.main_window_height = height
```

`MainWindow` in `resizeEvent` change it later

```
        self.second_window.main_window_width = width
        self.second_window.main_window_height = height
```

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        # keep MainWindow values in SecondWindow
        self.main_window_width = width
        self.main_window_height = height
        
        # dimensions widget applied to second window
        self.dimensions_win = Dimensions(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dimensions_win)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)

        self.second_window = SecondWindow(640, 480)
        self.second_window.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = event.size().width()
        height = event.size().height()

        # dimensions of main window passed to second window
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))

        # keep MainWindow values in SecondWindow
        self.second_window.main_window_width = width
        self.second_window.main_window_height = height
```

Or you can add extra function `update_data(width, height)` in `SecondWindow`.

And then `resizeEvent` has to run only `self.second_window.update_data(width, height)`

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        # keep MainWindow values in SecondWindow
        self.main_window_width = width
        self.main_window_height = height
        
        # dimensions widget applied to second window
        self.dimensions_win = Dimensions(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dimensions_win)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


    def update_data(self, width, height):
        
        self.main_window_width = width
        self.main_window_height = height

        self.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))

        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)

        self.second_window = SecondWindow(640, 480)
        self.second_window.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = event.size().width()
        height = event.size().height()

        self.second_window.update_data(width, height)
```

---

Other idea is to send `MainWidow` (`self`) to `SecondWindow` and keep it as i.e. `self.parent` and then `SecondWindow` will have access to values in `MainWidow` - ie. `self.parent.width()`

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        # dimensions widget applied to second window
        self.dimensions_win = Dimensions(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dimensions_win)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


    def update_data(self):
        
        width = self.parent.width()
        height = self.parent.height()

        print(width, height)
        
        self.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))
        self.dimensions_win.view_height.setText(str(height))

        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)

        self.second_window = SecondWindow(self, 640, 480)
        self.second_window.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.second_window.update_data()
```

Comment: Thank you for the working code. As a follow up how do I go about passing the dynamic size value from the resize function to the `SecondWindow()` for further processing instead of the static 640, 480?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Current code already gets dynamic size value from resize function and sends to `SecondWindow`. At this moment it sends directly into `QLabel` - `self.second_window.dimensions_win.view_width.setText(str(width))` but you can do the same to assign to some variable(s) in `SecondWindow` - `self.second_window.some_variable = (width, height)` - or in `Dimensions` -  `self.second_window.dimensions_win.some_variable = (width, height)`. Or execute some function in `SecondWindow` - `self.second_window.some_function(width, height)` - (or in `Dimensions`)

Comment: The dynamic size is being set to `QLabel` directly using the `resizeEvent` function I understand that. What I'm not clear about is how to get it to be seen by the whole `SecondWindow()` for example.  I tried `self.width`, `self.height` within the resize function and then `self.second_window = SecondWindow(self.width, self.height)` in the main window. But when I print width, height in `SecondWindow()` to terminal it prints built in "built-in object" instead of actual values.  I'm confused, could you provide a short example how this variable assignment would look like in this code?

Comment: in `SecondWindow` you could  create own variables for these values - `self.main_window_width` - because it may already have build-in function `width()` to set/get size of `SecondWindow`. And then you can set value at start in `SecondWindow.__init__` `self.main_window_width = width` and later change it in `resizeEvent` as `self.second_window.main_window_width = width`

Comment: I added example data with variables `self.main_window_width`. I also added example which sends `MainWindow` (`self`) to `SecondWindow` and it keeps it as `self.parent` and this way `SecondWindow` has access to all values in `MainWindow` (not only `width`, `height`)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to provide me with the code examples. I really appreciate it and will study them closely. Thanks again.